# É possivel manipular o url atual com php?

Tags: php, url, redirect

Opa, quero que o php envie um formulario GET, quando carrego a página.
Mas não estou conseguindo.

```
$forget = 'abc';
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?get='.$forget;
header('Location:'.$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma, assim você está utilizando a biblioteca cURL do PHP.

```
$forget = 'abc';
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?get='.$forget;

// Cria o cURL
$curl = curl_init();

// Seta algumas opções
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
]);

// Envia a requisição e salva a resposta
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Fecha a requisição e limpa a memória
curl_close($curl);
```